# Hangman Program

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

I'm working on a Hangman single view application game on iOS and I keep on getting stuck on the "letterButton" code. What I intended to do was to replace the dashes generated in `viewDidLoad` function with what the user will input through the letter buttons (all of the letter buttons are grouped under `letterButton`).

I tried replacing the dash array with the letter array but it simply tells me that the letter array is simply too big. I tried converting letter array to a string and then replacing the dash array with that but that didn't work either. So now I'm stuck and I do not know what to do to replace the dash array with letter inputs.

Please help (here is my code; please ignore the `dashArray [n]` part that was simply me trying desperately):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var letters: [UIButton]!
    var wordArray: [String] = ["cat", "dog", "hamster", "lizard"]
    var letterArray: [String] = ["Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"]
    var randomValue: Int = 0
    var word: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        randomValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wordArray.count)))
        word = wordArray[randomValue]
        letterArray = Array(arrayLiteral: word)

        let amount = word.characters.count
        let dashArray = Array(count: amount, repeatedValue: "_")
        let dashString = dashArray.joinWithSeparator(" ")

        wordLabel.text = dashString

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func letterButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let amount = word.characters.count

        var dashArray = Array(count: amount, repeatedValue: "_")

        dashArray [0] =
        dashArray [1] =
        dashArray [2] =
        dashArray [3] =
        dashArray [4] =
        dashArray [5] =
        dashArray [6] =

        let dashString = dashArray.joinWithSeparator(" ")
        wordLabel.text = dashString
    }

    @IBAction func resetButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let amount = word.characters.count
        let dashArray = Array(count: amount, repeatedValue: "_")
        let dashString = dashArray.joinWithSeparator(" ")

        wordLabel.text = dashString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got you right, you need to take a letter from a tapped button and replace a corresponding dash with this letter.

```
@IBAction func letterButton(sender: UIButton)
{
    guard let letterIndex = letters.indexOf(sender) else { return }

    let letter = letterArray[letterIndex]

    var dashString = wordLabel.text
    dashString[letterIndex] = letter
    wordLabel.text = dashString
}
```

**EDIT** Thank you for clarification, after reading the rules of a games it became clearer what's you are trying to achieve. The current problem is that you rewrite `letterArray` in `viewDidLoad`. My suggestion for fixing, sorry for possible mistakes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet var letterButtons: [UIButton]!
     @IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!
     var words: [String] = ["cat", "dog", "hamster", "lizard"]
     var letters: [String] = ["Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"]
     var word: String = ""

     override func viewDidLoad()
     {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         let randomValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(words.count)))
         word = wordArray[randomValue]

         let amount = word.characters.count
         let dashArray = Array(count: amount, repeatedValue: "_")
         wordLabel.text = dashArray.joinWithSeparator(" ")
     }

     @IBAction func letterButton(sender: UIButton)
     {
         guard let letterIndex = letters.indexOf(sender) else { return }

         let letter = letterArray[letterIndex]
         guard let indexInWord = word.characters.indexOf(letter) else {
             print("no such letter in this word")
             return
         }

         // since we have spaces between dashes, we need to calc index this way
         let indexInDashedString = indexInWord * 2

         var dashString = wordLabel.text
         dashString[indexInDashedString] = letter
         wordLabel.text = dashString
     }

     @IBAction func resetButton(sender: UIButton)
     {
         let amount = word.characters.count
         let dashArray = Array(count: amount, repeatedValue: "_")
         wordLabel.text = dashArray.joinWithSeparator(" ")
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but while your code does not have any errors when I implement it into the view controller, every time I press a button in the iphone stimulator it keeps on say : "fatal error: Index out of range" in the console even though both of these are the exact same size:                     let letter = letterArray[letterIndex]